# How do I draw rotated Rhombus?

Tags: c#, algorithm, rotation

I'm making a program in C# that will rotate rhombs made out of "+" but I don't know how to draw them. I tried to type Drawing method myself but I'm stuck, I just don't know how to draw it anymore. I'd like to keep the code as simple as possible, without any bitmaps or graphics. If someone would come up with Drawing method I would be greatful.
I tried to Draw it by finding Middle Point Between Points in loop but it didn't work well, so could someone help me please?
Punkt = Point

```
class romb
{
    private punkt p_up { get; set; } 
    private punkt p_left { get; set; } 
    private punkt p_right { get; set; } 
    private punkt p_down { get; set; } 

  private void MoveOneFrame()
  {
    punkt pivot = new punkt(((this.p_left.Get_x() + this.p_right.Get_x()) / 2), ((this.p_left.Get_y() + this.p_right.Get_y()) / 2));
    this.p_up = Rotate(p_up, pivot, 8);
    this.p_down = Rotate(p_down, pivot, 8);
    this.p_left = Rotate(p_left, pivot, 8);
    this.p_right = Rotate(p_right, pivot, 8);
  }

  private static punkt Rotate(punkt point, punkt pivot, double angleDegree)
  {            
    double angle = angleDegree * Math.PI / 180;
    double cos = Math.Cos(angle);
    double sin = Math.Sin(angle);
    int dx = point.Get_x() - pivot.Get_x();
    int dy = point.Get_y() - pivot.Get_y();
    double x = cos * dx - sin * dy + pivot.Get_x();
    double y = sin * dx + cos * dy + pivot.Get_y();

    punkt rotated = new punkt((int)Math.Round(x), (int)Math.Round(y));
    return rotated;
  }
}
```

Output: - And every rhombus should rotate itself around pivots(their centers)

```
      +
     + +
    +   +
   +     +
  +       +
 +         +
+           +        +
 +         +        + +
  +       +        +   +
   +     +        +     +
    +   +        +       +
     + +        +         +
      +        +           +
      +         +         +
     + +         +       +
    +   +         +     +
   +     +         +   +
  +       +         + +
 +         +         +      
+           +   
 +         +
  +       +
   +     +
    +   +
     + +
      +
```

Comment: Could you please show us what the output looks like? Orwhat it is supposed to look like?

Comment: Where is the `draw()` function / method?

Comment: Didn't add it in here as it doesn't work well after rotation. But I can add it if you need it

Comment: Could someone help me type a draw function for it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should keep your intermediate results (punkt.x and punkt.y as well as dx and dy) as double and only round them to integer when you finally display them.